# Solid metadata search and backup

Tags: metadata, vs-code, eclipse

I know this question has been posted before but wanted to revisit with a fresh set of eyes. So as you know, admins need to search an ENTIRE org's metadata for various reasons. For my use case, I need to find every instance of where the word 'Loan' is being used... (i,e, picklist values, report filters, flows, everything.)

In the past, Eclipse was pretty decent at doing this but, the force.com IDE is no longer available and it is suggested to move to VS Code. Fighting with getting a solid metadata dump through vscode package.xml is making this not a decent solution for this task.(too many errors)

I know there are appexchange apps like Satrang's Metadata Search but, I find that is not finding everything either. OwnBackup seems like it might work too? I JUST NEED A SIMPLE WAY TO FIND MY NEEDLE IN THE METADATA HAYSTACK! Is this too much to ask?

What are your experiences and tools that work reliably for you?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways this can be solved easily,

**1. By Building a package.xml for the whole org**

This is easily doable using a tool like [Package Builder](https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/) or a VSCode extension like this [one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator). Once you build the `package.xml` you can retrieve all the components using

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest <path_to_package.xml>
```

**2. Put all the metadata into an Unmanaged package**

The other alternative is to put all the metadata into a unmanaged package or changeset and then you can retrieve by name of the unmanaged package using below

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -n "<packagename/changesetname>"
```

The other alternatives are scripting it using `sfdx` CLI. Here is one handy [blogpost](https://meera-r-nair.blogspot.com/2020/09/an-easy-approach-to-take-metadata.html) that describes an approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to tackle this:

**Data search:**

You can create reports on each object to match your keyword and i know it might be tedious but not sure if you wish to search there. Thought of sharing.

**Metadata Search:**

To search across Apex class to find any apex variable/constructor/annotated method, i used Developer Console (File ==> Search in Files)
[image]

Also you could try this chrome extension as well [Salesforce advanced Code searcher].

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-advanced-code/lnkgcmpjkkkeffambkllliefdpjdklmi

Final approach would be to try comment from Mohith.

Let me know if it helps!